# Extending L.control.zoom with custom button

Tags: javascript, inheritance, leaflet, overriding, extends

I'm looking for a way to add an extra button to `L.control.zoom`. Leaflet is being loaded from a CDN and I'm using vanilla Javascript (no preprocessors or anything).

I was hoping there'd be something like `L.control.zoom.extend({})`, but unfortunately that doesn't exist. Trying `L.Control.extend({...L.control.zoom})` didn't work either.

For context, doing it the long way by copy-pasting the [original code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Zoom.js#L15) and adding the code for my custom button at line 42 would look like this:

```
let zoomControls = L.Control.extend({
    // @section
    // @aka Control.Zoom options
    options: {
        position: 'topleft',

        // @option zoomInText: String = '+'
        // The text set on the 'zoom in' button.
        zoomInText: '+',

        // @option zoomInTitle: String = 'Zoom in'
        // The title set on the 'zoom in' button.
        zoomInTitle: 'Zoom in',

        // @option zoomOutText: String = '&#x2212;'
        // The text set on the 'zoom out' button.
        zoomOutText: '&#x2212;',

        // @option zoomOutTitle: String = 'Zoom out'
        // The title set on the 'zoom out' button.
        zoomOutTitle: 'Zoom out'
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        var zoomName = 'leaflet-control-zoom',
            container = L.DomUtil.create('div', zoomName + ' leaflet-bar'),
            options = this.options;

        let locationLink = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'leaflet-bar-part leaflet-bar-part-single', container);
        L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(locationLink);
        locationLink.title = 'My location';
        let locationIcon = L.DomUtil.create('span', 'fa-lg fas fa-map-marker-alt', locationLink);
        L.DomEvent.on(locationLink, 'click', () => {
            alert('BUTTON CLICKED');
        });
        this._zoomInButton  = this._createButton(options.zoomInText, options.zoomInTitle,
                zoomName + '-in',  container, this._zoomIn);
        this._zoomOutButton = this._createButton(options.zoomOutText, options.zoomOutTitle,
                zoomName + '-out', container, this._zoomOut);

        this._updateDisabled();
        map.on('zoomend zoomlevelschange', this._updateDisabled, this);

        return container;
    },

    onRemove: function (map) {
        map.off('zoomend zoomlevelschange', this._updateDisabled, this);
    },

    disable: function () {
        this._disabled = true;
        this._updateDisabled();
        return this;
    },

    enable: function () {
        this._disabled = false;
        this._updateDisabled();
        return this;
    },

    _zoomIn: function (e) {
        if (!this._disabled && this._map._zoom < this._map.getMaxZoom()) {
            this._map.zoomIn(this._map.options.zoomDelta * (e.shiftKey ? 3 : 1));
        }
    },

    _zoomOut: function (e) {
        if (!this._disabled && this._map._zoom > this._map.getMinZoom()) {
            this._map.zoomOut(this._map.options.zoomDelta * (e.shiftKey ? 3 : 1));
        }
    },

    _createButton: function (html, title, className, container, fn) {
        var link = L.DomUtil.create('a', className, container);
        link.innerHTML = html;
        link.href = '#';
        link.title = title;

        /*
         * Will force screen readers like VoiceOver to read this as "Zoom in - button"
         */
        link.setAttribute('role', 'button');
        link.setAttribute('aria-label', title);

        L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(link);
        L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop);
        L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', fn, this);
        L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', this._refocusOnMap, this);

        return link;
    },

    _updateDisabled: function () {
        var map = this._map,
            className = 'leaflet-disabled';

        L.DomUtil.removeClass(this._zoomInButton, className);
        L.DomUtil.removeClass(this._zoomOutButton, className);

        if (this._disabled || map._zoom === map.getMinZoom()) {
            L.DomUtil.addClass(this._zoomOutButton, className);
        }
        if (this._disabled || map._zoom === map.getMaxZoom()) {
            L.DomUtil.addClass(this._zoomInButton, className);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not being explicit in the Leaflet [class customization tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html), there is a subtle distinction between *factories*, which are lowerCased and that you cannot extend, and *Classes*, which are PascalCased and on which you can use Leaflet `extend` mechanism:

```js
var MyNewZoomControl = L.Control.Zoom.extend({
  onAdd: function (map) {
    // your new method content
  }
}
```

That being said, if your new button does not really share functionality with the zoom buttons or is not "merged" with them, you could simply make a separate Control and insert it in the same corner position. There is also Leaflet EasyButton plugin which can help in this regard.